# Accessing Object Attribute Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing this in Rails 4:

```
ruleChange.old_value = (Filetype.new(:name => 'ritesh'))
```

However, on accessing `ruleChange.old_value`, it returns string 
as `#Filetype:0x007f87b2dce4c0`, instead of the object. As the result `ruleChange.old_value.name` is throwing the following exception:

> undefined method `name' for "Filetype:0x007f87b2dce4c0":String

What is wrong over here?

Comment: What do you use to handle your files ?
When do you ask for the old_value of ruleChange? (have you try on before_save)

Comment: @XavM can you please be more clear on your question?

Comment: Sory for my first comment, i misunderstood your code.
The real question is why do you want to assign a new value to old_value ?
Have you try `object.ruleChange_was` instead of old_value method ?

Comment: @XavM old_value is a string attribute in my database. I would eventually use "name" attribute to store the value in DB.
The real question is , why am i not able to assign an OBJECT reference to an attribute of a class???

Comment: When you say 
`The real question is , why am i not able to assign an OBJECT reference to an attribute of a class???`
You mean an attribute of an instance of a class, don't you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If old_value is a string attribute in your database, you can't store object in it.
You can store name attribute of that object (relevant only if name is unique)

A better practice would be to have a old_value_id to store the id of your old object.

Like this, you could do `current_object.old_value_id = my_old_object.id.`
And find your object like this : `MyOldObject.find(current_object.old_value_id).name`

Or you can define a belongs_to relationship to query your old object in a direct way : `current_object.my_old_object.name`

```
belongs_to :my_old_object, :class_name => 'my_object', :foreign_key => 'my_old_object'
```